# jQuery noConflict function

Tags: javascript, jquery

ok so I am trying to get a custom alert box working. I am using jquery 2.1.0 and have found out that the jAlert fucntion is not fully functional in jquery 2.1.0. Well the jAlert function I am using is not anyway.

I am now trying to sort out a no conflict script so I can use jquery 1.2.6 for only this function and the normal 2.1.0 for my other functions.

I have never used this no conflict before so my code may be completely wrong as I misunderstood the description about no conflict.

The below code is my jquery includes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.js"></script>
<!-- revert global jQuery and $ variables and store jQuery in a new variable -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
```

if the above code is incorrect then I do apologize as this is where I misunderstood the no conflict part if i did misread it. The reason why I haven't made `jquery-2.1.0.js` also a no conflict is because I didn't/don't think I need to make that version no conflict as that is the default jquery I wish to run and earlier jquery versions can't conflict with that. I also thought that if I make this a no conflict then I need to go through all of my functions using the newer version of jquery and pass them through the no conflict function code.

The no conflict function code is what I am having troubles with, that is if the above code is correct of course.

below is the original code i got from a google search and this is also from the page where I read about the no conflict jquery

```
jQuery_1_1_3('<button>Use jQuery 1.1.3</button>')
.click(function() {
alert('Top: ' + jQuery_1_1_3(this).offset().top + '\n' +
'jQuery: ' + jQuery_1_1_3.fn.jquery);
})
.appendTo('body');
```

Below is my edited version of the code that isn't working of course and is probably totally wrong as I am bad a js and really need to learn it more.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery_1()
(function() {
jAlert("Player details updated successfully","Success"); })
</script>
```

I am more then willing to use a more up to date version of the alert box jquery function but i just can't seem to find one using Google for some reason.

The script it self will run after someone has submitted a from and has been headed back to a page and that is where the alert box appears to let them know everything went fine.

This is the link to the noConflict description I got my code and also read

```
http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/
```

Comment: (I'd recommend building a JSFiddle for the rest of us to test this and help you out.) I'm not sure how the jAlert function operates with jQuery, but if you are using multiple versions of jQuery and need to use plugins with the older version, you usually need to load the plugins before you call `noConflict` (as shown in the blog post you referenced). Your example doesn't include the loading of the jAlert plugin so it's hard to determine if that's the problem.

Comment: If I put the original code in the place of my modified code then it works fine. it displays as a button what I need is for it to pop up without needing to click it.